# Schema/Metadata for members of organisation/Team Page

Tags: html, semantic-web, semantics, schema.org

I am building a team page for my client's website.

The team page contains a list of their employees along with following details:

1. image
2. Twitter Link
3. Facebook  Link
4. Full Name
5. Designation (CEO/Founder, etc).

How can I use metadata from [schema.org](http://schema.org/Person) for **adding all** of the above fields?

This is what I have come up so far.

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                <h1 itemprop="name">Team Member's Name</h1>
                <p>CEO</p>
                <img src="" alt="" itemprop="image">
                <a href="" class="facebookLink">Facebook Profile</a>
                <a href="" class="linkedInLink">LinkedIn Profile</a>
            </article>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Also, In terms of adding further meta data, I want to even add a additional property to a wrapper `<div>` with itemscope of the company that I am developing this website for.

So, that I add not only the meta data of each emplyoee, but I also add the company name (which is same for each employee).

Comment: Be sure to run your page in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool for errors or warnings: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool. That is, if it's not contained behind a login area :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- `name` for the full name (and if you want, [`givenName`](http://schema.org/givenName), [`familyName`](http://schema.org/familyName), and [`honorificPrefix`](http://schema.org/honorificPrefix)/[`honorificSuffix`](http://schema.org/honorificSuffix) in addition),
- `image` for the image,
- [`sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs) for the social media profiles, and
- [`jobTitle`](http://schema.org/jobTitle) for the designation.

To link the persons and the organization, look for appropriate properties that have `Person` as expected value (from `Organization`) or `Organization` as expected value (from `Person`).

A simple way could be:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">

  <ul>
    <li itemprop="founder" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></li>
    <li itemprop="employee" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></li>
    <li itemprop="employee" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

If your markup doesn’t allow this, Microdata’s `itemref` attribute might be useful ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161277/1591669)).

Answer (score 0):

According to schema.org this is how you add properties. You can learn more here. http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_types

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <a href="alice.html" itemprop="url">Alice Jones</a>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <a href="bob.html" itemprop="url">Bob Smith</a>
</div>
```

Then you can use the available property types from this table. http://schema.org/Person

However, since you're doing team members (employees), you may want to structure the markup around properties from Organization. http://schema.org/Organization