# How to refer to another item declaration from multiple other items, to satisfy schema.org?

Tags: schema, schema.org, semantic-markup

After a lot of searching for how to properly refer to one item from another, I found [this minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161277/3788043) that showcases how to refer to an `Organization` item as a `branchOf` from a `Hotel` item. It defines the attribute `itemprop="branchOf"` on the `Organization`, which becomes a property of the `Hotel` item after it references it.

```html
<div itemprop="branchOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" id="schema-organization">
 <h1 itemprop="name">The Hotel Chain</h1>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel" itemref="schema-organization">
 <h2 itemprop="name">Hotel Location 1</h2>
</div>
```

That example validates.

But now I need to add a `Person` that works for that `Organization`. I could use the same concept by defining `itemprop="worksFor"` on the `Organization`, and then referencing that from my `Person`, like so:

```html
<div itemprop="worksFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" id="schema-organization">
 <h1 itemprop="name">The Hotel Chain</h1>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel" itemref="schema-organization">
 <h2 itemprop="name">Hotel Location 1</h2>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="schema-organization">
    <div itemprop="name">John Doe</div>
</div>
```

And the `Person` correctly gets its `worksFor` attribute to show the `Organization` here.

But now I have to remove the `itemref` from the `Hotel`, otherwise it complains that it doesn't recognize a `worksFor` attribute. And if I do so, the `Hotel` is no longer referencing the `Organization` in any way, therefore it is not a branch of it.

So it seems that it's a either-or situation.

How I can I declare both? The `Person` needs to work for the `Organization`, and `Hotel` needs to be a branch of the `Organization`.

Comment: Advice: it's easier to 'describe' information using [turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(syntax)) [example](https://www.loc.gov/aba/pcc/bibco/documents/TurtleExamples.pdf) (note: don't use CURIEs; just model ?s ?p ?o statements). Once you have an information model, you can match it to the HTML. If you start with HTML, and the related microdata for each HTML element, you will have extreme difficulty in composing valid statements (valid as determined by the Google SDTT). HTML is a layout language; turtle is a thinking language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use itemid and reference the same itemid from each entity. e.g.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemid="#organization">
 <h1 itemprop="name">The Hotel Chain</h1>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel" >
 <h2 itemprop="name">Hotel Location 1</h2>
 <meta itemprop="branchOf" itemscope itemid="#organization"/>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <div itemprop="name">John Doe</div>
    <meta itemprop="worksFor" itemscope itemid="#organization"/>
</div>
```