# Define parent node before child in schema.org

Tags: microdata, schema.org

Is it obligatory to write `Product` node (parent) before `Offer` node (child) in DOM schema of schema.org or I can define `Offer` node without its parent node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.org never requires the existence of "parent" items (unless you use `itemprop` on an element with `itemscope`).

So this is totally fine:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
</html>
```

But even if you would want to add a Product, it doesn’t *have* to be a parent for Offer.

You can nest the Product under Offer:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can have both on the same level and use [`itemref`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161277/1591669):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="foo">
</div>

<div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="foo">
</div>
```