# Linking superEvent property in Microdata with itemref

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I'm adding Microdata to a page and I'm trying to associate a list of events to a superEvent, but I don't manage to make it work when checking at: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=

Here the concept code:

```html
<div id="main" itemscope="main" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
<span itemprop="name">Main
</div>
<div itemscope="event" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
<span itemprop="name">Event
<span itemprop="superEvent" itemref="main">
</div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems with your Microdata:

- `itemscope` is a boolean attribute, so you should not give it values like "main" or "event".
- The `itemref` attribute [can only be used on elements with `itemscope`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161277/1591669), so you can’t use it like that.

To link events via the [`subEvent`](http://schema.org/subEvent)/[`superEvent`](http://schema.org/superEvent) properties, you could either use the `itemref` attribute or nest the items.

With `itemref` and [`superEvent`](http://schema.org/superEvent), it could look like:

```html
<div itemprop="superEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" id="main">
  <span itemprop="name">Main</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="main">
  <span itemprop="name">Event</span>
</div>
```

With `itemref` and [`subEvent`](http://schema.org/subEvent), it could look like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="secondary">
  <span itemprop="name">Main</span>
</div>

<div itemprop="subEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" id="secondary">
  <span itemprop="name">Event</span>
</div>
```

Nesting (without using `itemref`) could look like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <span itemprop="name">Main</span>

  <div itemprop="subEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <span itemprop="name">Event</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this in the end:

```
<div id="main" itemprop="superEvent" itemscope="main" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
<span itemprop="name">Main
</div>
<div itemscope="event" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="main">
<span itemprop="name">Event
</div>
```