# Microdata for Product with Offer with Organization

Tags: html, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I'm trying to create Google Rich Snippets for my Product page.

I've created a Product using

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  ...
</div>
```

Inside this product, I have an Offer, created with

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add the seller property (an Organization) to the Offer, however, my HTML structure have the seller under the Product and not under the Offer.

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    ...
  </div>
  <div itemprop="seller" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

However, this doesn't seem to please the Google Structured Data testing tool.

I have then tried with using `itemref` on the Organization and using a `meta`-tag in the Offer

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="seller" itemref="provider">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="provider" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

But it still doesn't seem to recognize the seller as the Organization.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `itemref` correctly:

- The `itemref` attribute has to be specified on an element with `itemscope`.
- It has to reference an element with `itemprop`.

So your example would have to look like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="provider">
  </div>
  <div id="provider" itemprop="seller" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  </div>
</div>
```

But this does **not work**, because this way, the `seller` property will be added to both items, `Product` and `Offer`. This is not valid because `Product` can’t have the `seller` property.

So you would either have to change the nesting, or don’t use `Product` on the container `div`.

However, there’s also an ugly fix: add a dummy element with `itemscope`:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="provider">
  </div>
  <div itemscope>
    <div id="provider" itemprop="seller" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. So there's no way of keeping the old content-layout and have the proper schema markup?

Comment: @MadsOhmLarsen: If you can’t add a `div` element (so that `Product` is no the container for everything), I can’t think of a solution.