# SDTT: "A value for the image field is required"

Tags: html, image, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have this snippet in a `LocalBusiness` listing (based on [this example](https://whitespark.ca/blog/why-your-local-business-schema-sucks-and-how-to-make-it-better/)):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img itemprop="contentUrl" src="/images/trouwlocatiefotos/medium/315_24_83_Veranda-005.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

But [Google's structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) throws an error:

> `image`
>   A value for the `image` field is required.

Why is it throwing the error?

Testing the URL directly: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wonderweddings.com%2Fweddingvenues%2F315%2Fbeachclub-sunrise

[image]

Comment: And do you know why @type is of type Thing when I've defined that page as type LocalBusiness (see screenshot in post) or is that how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup snippet you posted doesn’t give the quoted error. So your actual markup is probably doing things differently.

It seems that your `image` property isn’t nested under the `LocalBusiness` item:

- Line 396: `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">`
- Line 372: `<div itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject'>`
- No `itemref` involved.

So your `LocalBusiness` item really doesn’t have an `image` property. Instead, the `image` property seems to be specified without any parent item (= `itemscope`), which is invalid.

Google’s SDTT probably ignores this error and parses the `ImageObject` as a top-level item, which is why it’s listed on its own (next to `LocalBusiness` and `BreadcrumbList`).

#### How to fix this?

If you can’t move the elements to nest them (like in your example snippet), you could make use of Microdata’s `itemref` attribute:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemref="business-image"></div>
```

```html
<div itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject' id="business-image"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I was unfamiliar with the `itemref` feature. Is it sufficient to have `itemref` point to an HTML element that contains the parent element? So, have the `image` point to something like this `<div id="whatever"><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">...</div></div>` like so: `<div itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject' itemref='whatever'>...</div>`?

Comment: @Flo: You have to use it the other way around (I edited my answer to include an example). And yes, you can specify the `id` on a `div` element not used for Microdata -- then all of the descendant `itemprop`s will be added to the `itemref`-ing item.

Comment: Ah, thanks. And what if I wanted to reference multiple items? e.g. `Reviews`, `BreadcrumbList` etc etc? Could I just add multiple `itemref` attributes?

Comment: @Flo: One `itemref` attribute with a value consisting of multiple ID tokens, separated with whitespace (`itemref="a b c"`). [Links to specifications, examples etc. in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984412/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

Add in snippet

In LocalBusiness schema, Required image, PriceRange field

Properties from Thing - Google returns errors..

Error:

image=A value for the image field is required.

priceRange=The priceRange field is recommended. Please provide a value if available.

Ans: add in code

1.For (image,logo,photo)= Image Object or URL   = An image of the item. This can be a URL or a fully described ImageObject.

2. For priceRange = Text = The price range of the business, for example $$$.

That items mandatory in LocalBusiness

Comment: Where is this mentioned.