# Schema.org: Store with multiple locations

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have to build the structured data for a store site, but this store is not located only at one place, it has about 5 subsidiaries, so I'm not sure if I have to create multiple `Store` item type or create an `Organization` and inside define the multiple subsidiaries.

This is what I have for one store only:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Store">
    <div>
        <h3 itemprop="name">Store 1</h3>
    </div>
    <address itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">1234 Fake St</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Locality</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">Region</span>, <span itemprop="addressCountry">Country</span>
    </address>
    <a itemprop="map" content="http://www.google.com" href="http://www.google.com">map</a>
    <div>
        <p><time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo-Su 10:00-21:00">Every day 10am-21pm </time></p>
        <p>Tel. <span itemprop="telephone" content="+1111111111">(1) 1111111 11</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should I repeat the above for each `Store`? Or need I to wrap `Store`s within an `Organization`?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here: [Using itemprop="branchOf" from schema.org Microdata to refer to LocalBusiness's parent company](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535779/using-itemprop-branchof-from-schema-org-microdata-to-refer-to-localbusinesss)

So, I have to declare the `Organization` with an `id`, and then use the `itemref` property.